# Entity Framework Code First timeouts when using default SQL instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012-express

I am seeing strange timeout behavior when connecting to a SQL Server 2012 Express default instance using Entity Framework - tested on 5.0.0 and 6.0.0.

If I use a server, by IP address, that is offline, EF seems to ignore any timeout values in the connection string.

This connection string always takes 73 seconds to timeout:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TestContext" connectionString="Server=10.0.0.2;Database=TestDb;User ID=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=5" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If I add a port, it takes 42 seconds:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TestContext" connectionString="Server=10.0.0.2,1433;Database=TestDb;User ID=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=5" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And any connectionstring with hostname takes 14 seconds, but if DNS resolves and host is offline; or online host doesn't have a SQL instance, it's back to 73 seconds e.g.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TestContext" connectionString="Server=dev-pc;Database=TestDb;User ID=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=5" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have tried:

```
context.Database.CommandTimeout = 5;
```

with no change in results.  This was expected since it doesn't even make it to the query.

Here is my inherited DbContext class:

```
namespace Test.DataLayer
{
    public class TestContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }           

        static TestContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(null);
        }    

        public TestContext()
            : base("Name=TestContext"){}           
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

Is this expected Entity Framework (or underlying provider) behavior?

Which timeout does it follow in this situation?

Since a 73 second timeout is too long, what can be done to speed up detection of offline SQL hosts?

Any other comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Francois

Answer (score 0):

**CommandTimeout** controls the time it waits for a specific command to execute (a SELECT for example); it will not have any impact when the server is unreachable and no command has been sent.
Try **[ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  As I mentioned in my post, I set `Connection Timeout=5` during all tests.

Comment: I did not scroll to see the end of your connection strings. My bad. try to set it from code and see if behavior differs? otherwise I'm not sure what else to say :)

Comment: Can't seem to find a way to set it in code since `context.Database.Connection.ConnectionTimeout` is readonly.  It does, however, reflect the `Connection Timeout=5` set in the connection string. Thanks anyway @AZ. :D